# Include extra rows in a has_many through relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

I'm not sure what the best way to tackle this is.

I have a has_many through relation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :animals,
           through: :farms

end
```

My issue deals with wanting to add in an extra `farm` from which to include animals even though technically the user does not own that farm.

If the user has 10 farms with ids ranging from 1 to 10, then what I want is to do something like include a farm with id 15 also.

So where as one would usually do `user.animals`. I'd like to do something like `user.animals.include("farms.id = ?", 15)` which would give results of the animals in all the users farms (1 - 10) and also include the animals from farm 15.

How would I accomplish this?

Eventually my queries look like `user.animals.reorder(created_at: :desc).includes(:owner, :farm).page(5).per(30).to_a`

What is the best way to include other farms in the query?

Comment: Looks like farm with id 15 is related to the user in a different manner than the farms with ids 1-10; probably requires a separate `has_many .. through .. ` relationship.

Comment: user.animals + Farm.where(id: 15) # or a scope should works too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the following method to your user model:

```
def animals_with_extra_farms(farm_ids = [])
  farm_ids += farms.map(&:id)
  Animal.where(farm_id: farm_ids)
end
```

Not that this will result in 2 database queries. There are other solutions that might be better from a performance point of view but this solution is very straight forward and easy to understand. And in my view easy code can be worth a few ms of performance.

If it turns out that this is a bottleneck you can always refactor it later.

Comment: This is actually a really good solution, imo. I didn't think about it this way.